# appending numbers to some lists during a loop

Tags: python, append

I want to write a program which gets 10 numbers and organizes them to tree lists and show their length. I tried this code:

```
for i in range(9):
    number=str(input("enter your number"))
list97=[]
list98=[]
list99=[]
if number[1]=="7" :
    list97.append(number)
elif number[1]=="8":
    list98.append(number)
else:
    list99.append(number)
print("length 97 is " + str(len(list97))"
print("length 98 is " + str(len(list98))"
print("length is 99 " + str(len(list99))"
```

And I get nothing in lists.

Comment: The code in the question is not syntactically correct. Also it is not clear what exactly you are trying to achieve. Can you please show an example of the inputs you are giving and the corresponding output you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need process the data inside for loop.

```
list97=[]
list98=[]
list99=[]
for i in range(9):
    number=str(input("enter your number"))
    if number=="7" :
        list97.append(number)
    elif number=="8":
        list98.append(number)
    else:
        list99.append(number)
print("length 97 is " + str(len(list97)))
print("length 98 is " + str(len(list98)))
print("length is 99 " + str(len(list99)))
```